# Sinatra's way to render multiple .erb files

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, session-cookies, erb

I have a web project that will render an HTML file, that is based on various .erb files.
I'm not sure about the best way, to do this, since each .erb file need to get specific information, such as cookie content.

Currently I have used this concept:

- I have a directory with all of my .erb files, which get rendered using:

  ERB.new(template).result
- the rendered HTML will get returned to the main .erb template, which will get again rendered by sinatra, using:

  erb :main
- the result is pretty good, but i don't have the chance to include content from session based cookies, since .erb can not access them

I am pretty sure, the sinatra framework provides a better way to do this. A good way would be...

```
require 'sinatra'
enable :sessions

get "/" do
content1 = erb :template1, :locals => { :cookie => session[:cookie] }
content2 = erb :template2, :locals => { :cookie => session[:cookie] }
erb :mainTemplate, :locals => { :content => [content1, content2] }
end
```

... but, unfortunately it doesn't work that easy :(

Does anybody has a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did for mine:

```
get '/Login' do verbose = params['verbose']
    cTest = MyTests.new("envo")
    result = cTest.login()

    if verbose == 'true'
        erb :newResultPage, :locals => {:result => result}
    elsif verbose == 'false'
        erb :resultPage, :locals => {:result => result}
    end
end
```

Basically, I use a conditional statement to determine which page to use. This one is based on parameters. You could also use return results, or what ever other conditions you like.

Comment: hmm, well that works grate if u only have a couple templates, but i am planning on using around 50. It would get kind of hard to use if..else or case conditions for such amount of templates.

Comment: Why do you need fifty different pages for one url? What makes them so different? You can have dynamic content in the pages but still have a "template" so to speak. That seems like an awful lot for one URL.

Comment: Each template will work as widget and will only contain a couple lines of mark up. i am also only going to need 6 to 8 of these templates at a time, but the templates will change on each request.

Comment: You might consider either using different url's for each template, or putting all the conditional statements into your erb. If you used the second option, you could have one page that would only display the data you wanted based on the parameters that you sent in.

Comment: okay. so sinatra can not render multiple templates in one url request?

Comment: Here is the link to Sinatra documentation. Don't know if you've seen it, but it may help. http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Views%20/%20Templates